# Sort results from high to low float array - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, arguments

Maybe this should be very easy but I am a bit lost on how to sort this data in a good way.

I got this query in a WordPress template to get some post_meta:

```
                        $args = array( 
                        'post_type' => 'page',
                        'fields' => 'ids',
                        'nopaging' => true,
                        'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                            'value' => array('page-provider.php'),
                            'compare' => 'IN',
                        ),
                            'prijs_sort' => array(
                                'key' => 'rwp_user_score',
                                'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,2)',
                                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                            ),
                        ),

                    );
```

With the data I get from this query get some more info and I want to final result sorted from High to Low.

```
                $pages = get_posts( $args );
                foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                    $get_average_score = get_post_meta( $page, 'rwp_user_score', true );
                    $gemiddelde_score = round($get_average_score, 1);

                    $get_review_count = get_post_meta( $page, $key = 'rwp_rating_0' , $single = false);
                    $get_review_count_aantal = array_count_values(array_column($get_review_count, 'rating_post_id'))[$page];

                    $name_provider = get_post_meta( $page, 'bedrijfsnaam_hosting_provider', false );
                    $gemiddeld_totaal = $gemiddelde_score * $get_review_count_aantal / 100;
                    echo implode(', ', $name_provider);
                    echo $gemiddeld_totaal;
                    var_dump($gemiddeld_totaal);
                    echo "<br/>";
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
```

I got `$name_provider;` and `$gemiddeld_totaal;` and I want the results to orderby `$gemiddeld_totaal;` from high to low. I tried a bunch of things but no luck so far. It is a float array and for some reason I am not able to sort the results.

This is a part of the var_dump of `$gemiddeld_totaal;`:

```
Page_title_1 0.05float(0.05) 
Page_title_2 0.784float(0.784) 
Page_title_3 0.144float(0.144) 
Page_title_4 0.066float(0.066) 
Page_title_5 0.048float(0.048) 
Page_title_6 0.048float(0.048)
```

How can I sort the results by `$gemiddeld_totaal;`? And the field `$name_provider;` also should sort with the sorting of `$gemiddeld_totaal;`.

**EDIT**
The results shoud look like:

```
Name provider 1  - Average Total 1
Name provider 2  - Average Total 2
Name provider 3  - Average Total 3
```

**EDIT 2 (adding one more data field)**
In de `foreach ( $pages as $page ) {`
I got one more data field that is needed in the output of the other foreach.

```
$shortcode = do_shortcode("[rwp_users_rating_stars id='0' post=\"$page\"]");
```

I tried some things but cant seem to figure out how to add this. This is the new line in the foreach. Could you explain me how to do this? Maybe I will understand it better then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is using [array_multisort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) the documentation says:

> We have an array of rows, but array_multisort() requires an array of
>   columns

```
$name_providers = array();
$gemiddelden_totaal = array();

foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $get_average_score = get_post_meta( $page, 'rwp_user_score', true );
    $gemiddelde_score = round($get_average_score, 1);
    $get_review_count = get_post_meta( $page, $key = 'rwp_rating_0' , $single = false);
    $get_review_count_aantal = array_count_values(array_column($get_review_count, 'rating_post_id'))[$page];
    $name_provider = get_post_meta( $page, 'bedrijfsnaam_hosting_provider', false );
    $gemiddeld_totaal = $gemiddelde_score * $get_review_count_aantal / 100;
    $name_providers[] = implode(', ', $name_provider); //we'll use this one as a column
    $gemiddelden_totaal[] = $gemiddeld_totaal; //we'll use this one as a column
    $data[] = array('name_provider' => implode(', ', $name_provider), 'gemiddeld_totaal' => $gemiddeld_totaal); //this one contains our rows
}
```

Once you've got that part you can sort both array's like:

```
$name_providers  = array_column($data, 'name_provider');
$gemiddelden_totaal = array_column($data, 'gemiddeld_totaal');
array_multisort($gemiddelden_totaal, SORT_DESC, $name_providers, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

**edit**
To get the desired result you could use something like :

```
foreach($gemiddelden_totaal as $key => $gemiddelde){
    echo $name_providers[$key] . '  - '  . $gemiddelde;
}
```

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you very much for this answer. What you are doing makes sense but now I got all the data sorted. What is the best way to output those values? Because when I try to put the array_multisort in a variable and echo it, I got 1... or is this not the right way to do this?

Comment: Hi there @user2812779 depending on how you want to display this information you could use a combination of [implode](https://php.net/implode) and [array_column](https://php.net/array_column). Simply using echo on an array won’t work.

Comment: Hello Peter M, I forget to put the $pages = get_posts( $args ); back so that is why it did not show anything. Ok so I put the array_multisort in a variable and that shows, 1111111111 and a var_dump shows 1bool(true) 1bool(true) 1bool(true). I am new to the array_colums so I realy have no clue how to use it in a proper way but I will try. thanks

Comment: @user2812779 Use [var_dump](https://php.net/var_dump) to see how variables are constructed.

Comment: I already did this. This is a part of the var_dump($gemiddelden_totaal);     array(1) { [0]=> float(0.05) } array(2) { [0]=> float(0.784) [1]=> float(0.05) } array(3) { [0]=> float(0.784) [1]=> float(0.144) [2]=> float(0.05) } array(4) { [0]=> float(0.784) [1]=> float(0.144) [2]=> float(0.066) [3]=>float(0.05) }. But my php skills let me down here to be honest. I already was glad to get this for but this is to much for me I think. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Do you think that if I ask a php developer he can help me out with this to make it work?:)

Comment: @user2812779 sure he would be able to help you, what should the result look like? You can add it to your question if needed.

Comment: Ok, I edited it in my question, not that hard I think but for me it is;)

Comment: @user2812779 updated the answer, doing this from my phone though so there could be some errors. It should be pointing you in the right direction though.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Could not done this on my own so thank you very very much!

Comment: once again, thank you very much. I have one more question, also to make me understand better. I edited my answer (EDIT 2). I got another data field in the first foreach but no luck of get it back in the second foreach in a good way. Could you help me?

Comment: @user2812779 Could you provide some more information on the desired result?

Comment: never mind I tried to figure out how you set up this foreach loop with the data in the arrays and somehow I figured it out and understand it a bit so thanks for all the input once again!:)